# .requestMatchers("/").permitAll() does not work

Tags: java, spring, authentication, security

403 error when connecting to "localhost:8080" or "localhost:8080/" in the following code.

It works well for other URL.

Only not work root URL.

I thought I could access localhost:8080 without authentication.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authprovider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authprovider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailsService());
        authprovider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authprovider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the Controller which handles your root to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check if Postman is not adding a token. Go to Auth tab, and make sure it says "No Auth".

Also, do you have a controller for root("/")? If not, try to create one. Most likely, these two steps will resolve your problem.

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the root url ("/") to open the HTML file in the static directory.